# How do you diagram global or shared state?

Tags: diagrams, finite-state-machine

Say you're building an FSM for something like a game and you've got states like:

- MainMenu
- Options
- SinglePlayer
- MultiPlayer

Your state diagram might look something like this:

[image]

Now say you have a shared state, `DevConsole`, (shows the console when tilde is pressed and receives KB input etc. I'm sure you've seen it before) such that no matter what state you're in, this state applies.

How do you diagram that?

*edit**

An example of how it would function would be like this:

```
public class StateMachine
{
    protected State sharedState;
    protected State previousState;
    protected State currentState;

    public void Update()
    {
        if(this.hasSharedState)
            this.sharedState.Update();

        if (this.previousState != null && this.previousState.IsExiting)
            this.previousState.Update();
        else
            this.currentState.Update();
    }

    // called by individual states
    public void ChangeState<StateType>()
    {
        // creates a new state adn sets its state machine owner to this machine
        this.previousState = this.currentState;
        this.previousState.Exit();
        this.currentState = StateBuilder.Build<StateType>(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: really? 7 out of 36 questions accepted? i was intrigued by the question but won't be putting any more effort into it than typing this comment..

Comment: What's wrong with two diagrams?

Comment: @Demian Brecht: Fair enough. There's some questions I've asked that could have accepted answers. I went through and accepted a few. Generally, however this is not an issue on p.se. See here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105/should-we-worry-about-accept-rate and here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-would-anyone-accept-an-answer

Comment: Are you looking for a [hierarchical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Hierarchically_nested_states) state diagram?

Comment: @Martin Wickman: Interesting. I'll have to take a closer look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your FSM does not have memory, for the `CONSOLE` state you would actually need a different "version" for every other state, otherwise there would be no way to determine to which state to return when you close the console.

You would be able to accomplish this with any automata that does have memory, like a [Pushdown Automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The FSM does have memory. See my edit for a bit of explanation.

Comment: @SnOrfus - In that case, you can make it a non-deterministic FSM, and simple have one state called `CONSOLE`, with each state transisting to it, and then `CONSOLE` transisting to every other state on whatever key closes the console. NFA can have multiple transitions on the same symbol.